# 3g coverage map - visualise lat, long, ping data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

Suppose I've been driving a set route with a 3g modem and GPS on my laptop, while my computer back at home records the ping delay. I've correlated ping with GPS lat/long, and now I'd like to visualise this data.

I've got about 80,000 points of data per day, and I'd like to display several month's worth. I'm especially interested in displaying areas where ping consistently times out (ie ping == 1000).

**Scatter plot**

My first attempt was with a scatter plot, with one point per data entry. I made the size of the point 5x larger if it was a timeout, so it was obvious where these areas were. I also dropped the alpha to 0.1, for a crude way to see overlaid points.

```
# Colour
c = pings 
# Size
s = [2 if ping < 1000 else 10 for ping in pings]
# Scatter plot
plt.scatter(longs, lats, s=s, marker='o', c=c, cmap=cm.jet, edgecolors='none', alpha=0.1)
```

[image: Scatter plot]

The obvious problem with this is that it displays one marker per data point, which is a very poor way to display large amounts of data. If I've drive past the same area twice, then the first pass data is just displayed on top of the second pass.

**Interpolate over an even grid**

I then had a try at using numpy and scipy to interpolate over an even grid.

```
# Convert python list to np arrays
x = np.array(longs, dtype=float)
y = np.array(lats, dtype=float)
z = np.array(pings, dtype=float)

# Make even grid (200 rows/cols)
xi = np.linspace(min(longs), max(longs), 200)
yi = np.linspace(min(lats), max(lats), 200)

# Interpolate data points to grid
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear', fill_value=0)

# Plot contour map
plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,15,linewidths=0.5,colors='k')
plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

From [this example](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data)

This looks interesting (lots of colours and shapes), but it extrapolates too far around areas I haven't explored. You can't see the routes I've travelled, just red/blue blotches.

If I've driven in a large curve, it'll interpolate for the area between (see below):

[image: Interpolation problems]

**Interpolate over an uneven grid**

I then had a try at using meshgrid (`xi, yi = np.meshgrid(lats, longs)`) instead of a fixed grid, but I'm told my array is too big.

Is there an easy way I can create a grid from my points?

---

**My requirements:**

- Handle large data sets (80,000 x 60 = ~5m points)
- Display duplicate data for each point either by averaging (I assume interpolation will do this), or by taking a minimum value for each point.
- Don't extrapolate too far from data points

I'm happy with a scatter plot (top), but I need some way to average the data before I display it.

(Apologies for the dodgy mspaint drawings, I can't upload actual data)

---

**Solution:**

```
# Get sum
hsum, long_range, lat_range = np.histogram2d(longs, lats, bins=(res_long,res_lat), range=((a,b),(c,d)), weights=pings)
# Get count
hcount, ignore1, ignore2 = np.histogram2d(longs, lats, bins=(res_long,res_lat), range=((a,b),(c,d)))
# Get average
h = hsum/hcount
x, y = np.where(h)
average = h[x, y]
# Make scatter plot
scatterplot = ax.scatter(long_range[x], lat_range[y], s=3, c=average, linewidths=0, cmap="jet", vmin=0, vmax=1000)
```

Comment: I would suggest to cluster the data, i.e. combine points which are within a certain distance and display their average/minimum in a scatter plot. That being said, I don't know much about cluster algorithms in python, but I'm sure you can easily find some ideas on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify your question, you have two set of points, one for ping<1000, one for ping>=1000.
Since the count of points is very large, you can't plot them directly by scatter(). I created some sample data by:

```
longs = (np.random.rand(60, 1) + np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 80000)).reshape(-1)
lats = np.sin(longs) + np.random.rand(len(longs)) * 0.1

bad_index = (longs>0) & (longs<1)
bad_longs = longs[bad_index]
bad_lats = lats[bad_index]
```

(longs, lats) is points for ping<1000, (bad_longs, bad_lats) is points for ping>1000

You can use numpy.histogram2d() to count the points:

```
ranges = [[np.min(lats), np.max(lats)], [np.min(longs), np.max(longs)]]
h, lat_range, long_range = np.histogram2d(lats, longs, bins=(400,400), range=ranges)
bad_h, lat_range2, long_range2 = np.histogram2d(bad_lats, bad_longs, bins=(400,400), range=ranges)
```

h and bad_h are the points count in every little squere area.

Then you can choose many methods to visualize it. For example, you can plot it by scatter():

```
y, x = np.where(h)
count = h[y, x]
pl.scatter(long_range[x], lat_range[y], s=count/20, c=count, linewidths=0, cmap="Blues")

count = bad_h[y, x]
pl.scatter(long_range2[x], lat_range2[y], s=count/20, c=count, linewidths=0, cmap="Reds")

pl.show()
```

Here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

longs = (np.random.rand(60, 1) + np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 80000)).reshape(-1)
lats = np.sin(longs) + np.random.rand(len(longs)) * 0.1

bad_index = (longs>0) & (longs<1)
bad_longs = longs[bad_index]
bad_lats = lats[bad_index]

ranges = [[np.min(lats), np.max(lats)], [np.min(longs), np.max(longs)]]
h, lat_range, long_range = np.histogram2d(lats, longs, bins=(300,300), range=ranges)
bad_h, lat_range2, long_range2 = np.histogram2d(bad_lats, bad_longs, bins=(300,300), range=ranges)

y, x = np.where(h)
count = h[y, x]
pl.scatter(long_range[x], lat_range[y], s=count/20, c=count, linewidths=0, cmap="Blues")

count = bad_h[y, x]
pl.scatter(long_range2[x], lat_range2[y], s=count/20, c=count, linewidths=0, cmap="Reds")

pl.show()
```

The output figure is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, `np.histogram2d` is very helpful. Can you think of a way to easily make size/colour represent average/minimum ping value at that point, rather than a count?

Comment: To calculate average, you can call np.histogram2d with weights = pings, this will sum all the pings in the square area. and then divide the result with count.

Comment: Thanks @HYRY, I've marked your answer as accepted, and added the solution ended up using into the end of my question.

Answer (score 1):

The [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) libraries including the [Python API](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython) and associated utilities, particularly [gdal_grid](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) should work for you.  It includes a number of interpolation and averaging methods and options for generating gridded data from scattered points.  You should be able to manipulate the grid cell size to get a pleasing resolution.

GDAL handles a number of data formats, but you should be able to pass your coordinates and ping values as CSV and get back a PNG or JPEG without much trouble.

Keep in mind lat/lon data is not a planar coordinate system.  If you intend to incorporate you results with other map data you'll have to figure out what map projection, units, etc. to use.